# QWebView, QWebFrame evaluateJavaScript fails every other time

Tags: javascript, json, qwebview

Starting with the Fancybrowser example, I wrote a little script player that 
clicks through web forms and such, filling in fields, clicking NEXT etc.

Problem.  I found that evaluateJavascript() failed on the first invocation on anything
more complicated than 'var x = "something";
In other words, any function definition, anything complex would not work.

Apparently the script evaluation engine gets left in some weird state.  The only way 
that I've found to clear it is to send the a bad javascript string 'syntax error;' to it.
It FAILS to run that simple javascript, but at least it clears it's state.  And the next
script runs successfully, parsing complex files.

What's GOING ON HERE?  I hate to send garbage to WebKit just to make it work.

Comment: Could you please provide sample code, as in my experience the javascript engine works as expected.